# pointers and increment operator

Tags: c++, pointers, post-increment, c-strings

I have the following simple code:

```
#include<iostream>

const char str[]={'C','+','+'};

int main()
{ 
  const char *cp=str;                     
  std::cout<<*str<<std::endl;

  while (*cp++>0)  
    std::cout<<*cp;
}
```

can't understand why it prints

```
C
++
```

Shouldn't the postfix increment operator evaluate the expression but return the value unchanged? (I double checked precedence of increment, dereference and relational operators and it should work)

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: I think that I'm dereferencing cp before it get incremented. So I'm expecting it to print the entire string.

Comment: You are printing `'\0'` to the `cout` stream. This is UB as pointed by some people in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888851/what-does-cout-na-n-do/30888904).

Comment: "So I'm expecting it to print the entire string". It is printing the entire string, it's just inserting an extra newline also (and a `\0`)

Comment: no, because the first call to cout is independent of the second call. Maybe my code isn't clear enough. But I found my error so thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
while (*cp++>0)  
    std::cout<<*cp;
```

The postfix operator increments the value after *the expression* it was used in is evaluated. There are two different expressions referring to `cp` in this `while` statement though: the first one tests and increments, but the second one prints. Since the second one is a separate statement, the increment has already happened by then.

i.e. you currently test against `'C'`, *then increment regardless of the result*, then print `'+'` through the now-incremented pointer. If it were iterating a string literal, this code would also increment once after reaching the `0`, although you don't see a result of that because it skips the print (because it iterates over a hand-created array with no null terminator, what it actually does here is fall off the end and exhibit undefined behaviour; this is a big error in itself, you can't rely on there being a zero at the end if one wasn't put there).

Comment: whoa, yes I got it, the first increment happens no matter what in the while condition.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

This line prints: C and the carriage return.

```
std::cout<<*str<<std::endl;
```

Then you are looping on following characters but there is no ending character (c.f. buffer overflow)
Here's the code fixed up.

```
#include <iostream>

const char str[]={'C','+','+', '\0'};

int main()
{ 
    const char* cp = str;                     
    std::cout<< *str << std::endl;

    while (*cp++ > 0)  
    std::cout << *cp;

    return 0;
}
```

This code is even simpler if you want to display "C++"

```
#include <iostream>

const char str[]={'C','+','+', '\0'};

int main()
{ 
    const char* cp = str;                     

    while (*cp > 0)
        std::cout << *cp++;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even simpler: `std::cout << str << '\n';` …

Answer (score 0):

> shouldn't the postfix increment operator evaluate the expression but return the value unchanged?

No, postfix operator returns the value of operand first then, only it is increased by 1.

here,

```
while (*cp++>0)  
    std::cout<<*cp;
```

by the time it reaches `std::cout<<*cp;` the value of `cp` is incremented, and hence the result `++`.

Comment: That’s exactly what OP said.

Comment: returns the value unchanged?? really?

Comment: @luca     *cp++ > 0
it will evaluate the expression first, `*cp > 0`

then it will increment the pointer `cp++`

Comment: Well, yeah: “returns the vale first [then increments it]” and “returns the value unchanged” are really synonymous.

Comment: "unchanged" implies that it never actually changes, which is incorrect. I'd prefer "returns the original value". This emphasizes that the `cp` does change.

Comment: @KonradRudolph   Yes that's why my comment, that it gets incremented after the evaluation of the expression, because of that "Unchanged" word.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
while(*cp++>0)
```

The post increment operator is executed, after the evaluation happens.

i.e. cp points to `C` during the first evaluation of the while condition.

So,

```
*cp => 'C' which is greater than 0.
```

Before moving to the next line (Inside the loop), the post increment operator gets executed, making cp point to the first `+`

After `+` is printed, the while condition is executed again, this time *cp returns '+'. since `'+' > 0`, the control enters the loop for the second time.

Before entering the loop, the post increment operator executes again, making cp point to the second '+', which is printed.

Now, while condition is executed for the third time. Here, `*cp` returns `+`. Thus, control enters the loop again.

Before entering the loop, post increment executes again. This time, it makes cp point to the next character, which is `\0`.

The `\0` is printed, which makes no difference in this code. Then, when the while condition executes again, *cp returns \0, which is not > 0. So, the condition fails.

**Edit:** Saw in the comments that you wanted to print the entire String in the same line. Change the loop to:

```
while(*cp > 0)
    std:cout<<*cp++;
```