# Is binary flag necessary for file input/output?

Tags: c++, fstream

I was able to read and write without setting any binary flag:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct C {

    C(int X = 0, int Y = 0) :x(X), y(Y) {}

    int x; int y;
};

int main()
{
    C Point1(4, 9);
    C Point2;

    std::fstream IOFile("Test.txt", 
        std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);

    IOFile.write((char const*)&Point1, sizeof(C));

    IOFile.seekg(std::ios_base::beg);

    IOFile.read((char*)&Point2, sizeof(C));

    IOFile.close();
}
```

The write and read functions returned the same data regardless of whether binary flag was set or not. So, where is this flag really necessary?

Comment: This code doesn't prove that what you read is what you wrote. It only proves that an error isn't generated.

Comment: Technically this is undefined behavior to [write to a text stream a character outside the printable characters range](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30891329/1708801). This will work on many systems but it could break in the future.

Comment: In general you can't binary dump objects to files and back and expect it to work reliably.

Answer (score 3):

It is system dependent. UNIX/Linux does not make any difference between text mode and binary mode. Windows does though. So for maximum portability use binary whenever you read/write streams of raw data.

Comment: I am using Windows OS. Would there be much difference?

Comment: Yes it will, since the newlines are translated into `\r\n`. It happens to work in your case since you don't encounter those characters (13 and 10 in ASCII, respectively). But, to have a portable and correct code, you need to use binary mode.

Answer (score 2):

On UNIX, there is no difference.

On Windows, LF (`\n`) is translated into the Windows CRLF (`\r\n`) line ending sequence when writing and vice versa when reading. That's if the file is opened in text mode. In binary mode no translation is done.

Pre-OSX Macs used CR (`\r`) as line endings, so `\n` was turned into `\r` when writing and the reverse when reading. OSX is a UNIX-based operating system so it performs no translation.