# Remove whitespace for the output in c++

Tags: c++

The following code is for printing the elements of a matrix in spiral order. The program works fine. The problem, however, is that the test compiler against which I'm checking the program, doesn't accept trailing white spaces at the end of the output. Could anyone give me some ideas as to how I can get around the last white space being added at the output?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string input;
  int value;
  int matrixA[10][10],matrixB[10][10],result[10][10];
  int k=0,l=0,m=0,n=0;
  int i=0,j=0;

  cout<<"Enter first matrix:\n";

   while(true)
{
    //Read string from keyboard
    getline(std::cin,input);
    if(input.empty())
    {
        break;
    }
    //Parse string using sring stream
    stringstream ss(input);
    j=0;
    while (ss >> value)
    {
        matrixA[i][j]=value;
        j++;
        if (ss.peek()==' ')
            ss.ignore();
    }
    i++;
}
 //Assign row and column length
k=i;
l=j;

cout<<"Enter second matrix:\n";
i=0;
while(true)
{
    //Read string from keyboard
    getline(std::cin,input);
    if(input.empty())
    {
        break;
    }
     //Parse string using sring stream
    stringstream ss(input);
    j=0;
    while (ss >> value)
    {
        matrixB[i][j]=value;
        j++;
        if (ss.peek()==' ')
            ss.ignore();
    }
    i++;
}
//Assign row and column length
m=i;
n=j;

bool first=true;
if(l==m)
{
    //Multiplication logic
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            result[i][j]=0;
            for(int d=0;d<m;d++)
            {
                result[i][j]=result[i][j]+matrixA[i][d]*matrixB[d][j];

            }
        }
    }

     cout<<"The product is:\n";
    //Display matrix result
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {

            cout<<result[i][0];

        }
        for(j=1;j<n;j++)
        {
            cout<<' '<<result[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n";

    }
}
else
{
    cout<<"The two matrices have incompatible dimensions.\n";
}  

return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the bad typing!

Comment: Replace last `cout << result[i][j] << " ";` with `cout << result[i][j] << (j == n - 1 ? endl : " ");`. And also remove the `cout << endl;` after that loop

Comment: @ionagamed: there is a compile error for "endl".

Comment: `endl` and `" "` are not same type so you will get error. Replace `endl` with `"\n".` Remotely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888851/what-does-cout-na-n-do/30888904. So my bad advice is `cout << " \n"[j == n-1]`

Comment: @Melebius: Like this: the expect output is "18", but my output is "18[whitespace]".

Comment: @ZiWeiPan I meant the compile error. However, following Mohit Jain’s comment should make it work.

Comment: @Mohit Jain: I try it, but it does not work. May be you can see my update code.

Comment: You can also print the first element out of the inner loop: `...cout<<result[i][0];for(j=1;j<n;j++){cout<<' '<<result[i][j];}cout << '\n';...`

Comment: You should really make the code more readable... for example, replace `" \n"[j==n-1]` by `(j==n-1)[" \n"]`... oh the irony... sorry about that

Comment: @Bob__: It gives me the result like "2828 14". It seems like the output will repeat the first column.                    "7979 44"

Comment: In the updated question code, shouldn't `for(j=0;j<n;j++)` actually be `if (0 < n)`? This would make much more sense if you want to print the first element as stand alone and all following elements with a prefix

Comment: @grek40: Yes, you are right! Thanks!

Comment: I meant the cout<<result[i][0] inside the i loop, but **outside** the j loop. Anyway, what do you mean with "spiral order"?